# Gradient algorithm for Convolutional Blind Source Separation

Tags: convolution, source-separation, gradient, blind-deconvolution

I'm trying to implement an algorithm for Convolutional Blind Source Separation (CBSS) based on the ALS algorithm for common BSS on [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220870653_Regularized_Alternating_Least_Squares_Algorithms_for_Non-negative_MatrixTensor_Factorization).

On this paper, the problem is formulated by (noise suppressed):

$$\boldsymbol Y=\boldsymbol{AS}$$

which $\boldsymbol A$ and $\boldsymbol S$ must be estimated. The function to be optimized is:

$$J(\boldsymbol Y||\boldsymbol{AS})=\frac{1}{2}||\boldsymbol Y-\boldsymbol{AS}||^2_F+\alpha_A||\boldsymbol A||_{L1}+\alpha_S||\boldsymbol S||_{L1}$$

and the gradients are calculated as:

$$\frac{\partial J(\boldsymbol Y||\boldsymbol{AS})}{\partial \boldsymbol A}=(\boldsymbol{AS}-\boldsymbol Y)\boldsymbol S^T+\alpha_A sign(\boldsymbol A)$$

$$\frac{\partial J(\boldsymbol Y||\boldsymbol{AS})}{\partial \boldsymbol S}=\boldsymbol A^T(\boldsymbol{AS}-\boldsymbol Y)+\alpha_S sign(\boldsymbol S)$$

$S$ is the sources matrix ($N\times P$), $Y$ the observed signals matrix ($M\times P$), $A$ is the mixture matrix ($M\times N$) and the $sign(.)$ function is applied element-wise. $\alpha_A$ and $\alpha_S$ are lagrange multipliers for sparcity regularization on $\boldsymbol A$ and $\boldsymbol S$, respectively.

I want to expand this method for CBSS with $N$ sources and $M$ observed signals and $P$ samples in each signal, where the problem is formulated by ($\circledast$ for circular convolution):

$$\boldsymbol Y=\boldsymbol H\circledast\boldsymbol S$$

where $\boldsymbol H$ is a matrix of discrete LTI systems:

$$\boldsymbol H=
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{00}[n]&h_{01}[n]&\dots&h_{0M}[n]\\
h_{10}[n]&h_{11}[n]&\dots&h_{1M}[n]\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
h_{N0}[n]&h_{N1}[n]&\dots&h_{NM}[n]\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So, the $i$-th row of $\boldsymbol Y$ is calculated by:

$$\boldsymbol y_i=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}h_{ij}[n]\circledast\boldsymbol s_j[n]=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\sum_{p=0}^{P-1}h_{ij}[p]\boldsymbol s_j[n-p]$$

$\boldsymbol s_j[n]$ been the source signal represented by the $j$-th row of $\boldsymbol S$.

So, what should be the gradient functions to expand the ALS algorithm to CBSS in this case?

$$\frac{\partial J(\boldsymbol Y||\boldsymbol H\circledast\boldsymbol S)}{\partial \boldsymbol H}=?$$

$$\frac{\partial J(\boldsymbol Y||\boldsymbol H\circledast\boldsymbol S)}{\partial \boldsymbol S}=?$$

$h_{ij}[n]$ can be seen as a vector of $P$ elements, so $\boldsymbol H$ can be a $M\times N\times P$ tensor

If needed, gradient in $\boldsymbol H$ can be divided in several derivatives of each LTI system, maybe it makes algorithm slower, but feasible:

$$\frac{\partial J(\boldsymbol Y||\boldsymbol H\circledast\boldsymbol S)}{\partial h_{ij}}=?$$

Or even in terms of the gradient of each coefficient of each LTI system:

$$\frac{\partial J(\boldsymbol Y||\boldsymbol H\circledast\boldsymbol S)}{\partial h_{ij}[k]}=?$$

I find a way to estimate the system and the source signals in a convolutional BSS model by using it's Fourier Transform so the convolution becomes a product and the model is estimated in the frequency domain. But is there a way to to it directly from the time domain?